# Need Div to take up space for layout, will not fill space

Tags: html, css

I need a column in a specific row in my .html file to take up space but it will be empty space. When I have it in my Div for the row and set the div's class to the correct column size it will not show. I have the opening and closing div's set

```
<div class = "row-2">

    <div class = "col-5">
    </div>

    <footer class = "col-7">

    *other code*

    </footer>
</div>
```

Should have space left of the footer for a column width of 5, the footer is all the way to the left instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the width and height elements to set sizes and use different measuring units to do so. For example:

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

This will make the div 1/2 of the parent element's width and 1/2 of the total screens height. The % symbol represents a percentage of the parent element width and the vh measurement is the view port height in percentage. For more info you can read the units and measurements section at w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp